# Ionic Iframe file location not found in Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using an iframe inside my home.html as follows.

```
  <iframe src='../../assets/chatbot/chatbot.html' width='100%' height='80%' border='none' frameBorder='0' seamless='seamless'></iframe>
```

It works fine when running in localhost in a web browser. The problem comes when I build apk and installed in the android device. It says

```
The webpage at
file:///assets/chatbot/chatbot.html could not be loaded because:
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

How can I specify path to this html file inside iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the issue.

specifying the path as follows solved the problem.

```
src='assets/chatbot/chatbot.html'
```